# Eclipse Spring Source: Can't rename java class name's references with project has layers

Tags: eclipse, springsource

[image]

I want to rename my class and its references but I can't make it. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you offer some more details please? How are you trying to rename it (the steps you took), what the error is (if any) etc.

Comment: I F2 my class file and rename it on a popup with the "Update references" checked, but I can rename only this class and its references  remain with the old names, so I got errors